# What should a freelancer do to prepare himself/herself for the transition to working as an employee?

Tags: work-environment, new-job

Freelancers are used to their own schedule/deadlines/whatnot. If a freelancer has to take employment (for whatever reason), they will have to start working in the more rigid workplace.

What should a freelancer do to prepare himself/herself for the transition to working as an employee?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few general things that might help:

- Get the dress code and note how people actually dress when you are there for the interview, don't forget to check footwear and make sure it isn't a causal Friday. Go shopping if you need to.
- Make the commute at least once during the time you will normally commute. Rush hour traffic can really change travel times, know what you are in for before your first day.
- Start waking up and going to sleep on schedule a few days before so your body can start to adjust.
- Bring headphones and music you can work to; there is probably going to be more noise than you are used to.
- Bring a jacket/sweater and maybe a fan if allowed, since you won't have as much control over your environment

Otherwise, just be prepared to be observant and flexible as you get a feel for your workplace and how you will fit into it.

Answer (score 3):

The most important rule: the freelancer should acknowledge that he is on the other side of the rules now. He is going to make some things he doesn't like, he is going to attend some meetings he will find to be very boring. Then there are lots of advantages and disadvantages for the transition that he will discover later.